# MACRO PARA ALIMENTAR UN ARCHIVO XLS DESDE N ARCHIVOS

Tags: excel, macros

Macro para alimentar un archivo xls desde varios (la cantidad puede variar) archivos xls contenidos en un directorio especifico.

El formato es el sgte:

Archivos de origen: Contienen un encabezado y un solo registro debajo del mismo. (A1:I2)

Archivo destino: Debe contener el mismo encabezado y almacenar los datos que se encuentran en cada archivo de origen (A2:I2).

Cada vez que se ejecute el macro debería limpiar los datos del archivo destino y obtener los datos de todos los archivos de una carpeta especifica.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub OpenAndSaveNuevoLibro(archivoOrigen As String, contador As Integer)
Dim LibroOrigen As Workbook, LibroDestino As Workbook, LibroOrigen2 As Workbook
Dim FileNm As String, sContador As String

 Set LibroOrigen = Workbooks.Open(archivoOrigen)
 Set LibroDestino = ThisWorkbook
 sContador = contador + 1

With LibroDestino
    LibroOrigen.Sheets("hoja1").Rows("2:2").Copy .Sheets("hoja1").Rows(sContador)
    .Save
    '.Close Savechanges:=False
End With

LibroOrigen.Close Savechanges:=False

End Sub

Sub ProcesarArchivos()
'1. Eliminar registros de Destino (desde fila 2, hasta el final)
'2. Recorrer los archivos de directorio de entrada
Call OpenAndSaveNuevoLibro("D:\RAIZ\in\entrada.xls", 1)
End Sub
```